# The posgres filter "not contains" doesn't work as I expect

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am doing the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Organization"
WHERE "allowedDomains" @> '{"gmail.com"}'
AND NOT "blacklist" @> '{"example@gmail.com"}';
```

I expect this query to list all organizations that have `gmail.com` in the `allowedDomains` (string[]) and NOT to include the organization if that organization has in `blacklist` (string[]) `example@gmail.com`.

When I do:

```
SELECT *
FROM "Organization"
WHERE "allowedDomains" @> '{"gmail.com"}'
```

I get

[image]

And then I add the `AND NOT "blacklist" @> '{"example@gmail.com"}';`

And get 0 results.

(Just to clarify, I am just using example@gmail.com to redact the email, the query email I'm trying to filter is correctly typed)

Comment: So you want to return 1 row name: one with blank blacklist? If yes, you can include checking for NULL value to return it.

Comment: It works here:  https://dbfiddle.uk/2cwptfZd

Comment: @jose_bacoy yes I expect to receive the one that has no blacklisted email, what do you mean checking for null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any of two arrays is `null` the result of the operator `@>` is also `null`. Use [`coalesce()`.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)

```sql
SELECT *
FROM "Organization"
WHERE "allowedDomains" @> '{"gmail.com"}'
AND NOT coalesce("blacklist", '{}') @> '{"example@gmail.com"}';
```

Comment: Thank you very much,  since I was actually trying to do this for https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#not-1
what is the generic name of the issue I looking for since I am not finding anytthing with "prisma coalesce"

Comment: Is there other ways of doing this other that coalesce that are not contrived? because maybe prisma does not have coalesce but it has some other way of doing this

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know prisma. The ideal solution would be to store an empty array `{}` instead of `null`, then you don't need `coalesce()`.

Comment: @Trufa: you can explicitly check for null `where .. AND (blacklist is null or not blacklist @> ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's very useful, I'm trying to generate that query with prisma

Comment: @Trufa: `coalesce()` is part of the SQL standard. Any self-respecting obfuscation layer (aka "ORM") should support that